# Negative variance component of random effect

Tags: r, random-effects-model

I encountered a problem related to negative variance component of random effects ( I think SAS and R both constrain these negative values to zero) in mixed model. Almost 5 out of 20 variables in my dataset have this kind of problems. I did scatter plot, box plot and histogram plot of these variables and can't find any common characteristics of them. One of them has a very obvious outlier, another one has discrete values, but the other three seem very good to fit a normal distribution.

So how can I explain why I have these zeros in my variance component matrix?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example in your question. In other words, your codes. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677586/random-effects-variance-of-intercept-being-zero/26678200#26678200